# Admin and Manager user is redirected to route /home when logging in but must be redirected to route /admin/home and /manager/home respectively

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I am studying multiple authentication.

In particular I have 3 users:

1. a **User** user who must be redirected to ***/home*** when logging in
2. an **Admin** user who must be redirected to ***/admin/home*** when logging in
3. a **Manager** user who must be redirected to ***/manager/home*** when logging in

The problem I am having is when I log in as Admin and as Manager I am redirected to the route /home and then I get the error

> **["You do not have permission to access for this page."]**

However, once I log in, if I manually enter the route of interest I can log in without problems.

So the problem is the route addressing once I try to log in as Admin or as Manager.
For the User user I'm not having any problems.

This is my code:

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
  
Auth::routes();
  
/*------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
All Normal Users Routes List
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------*/
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:user'])->group(function () {
  
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
  
/*------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
All Admin Routes List
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------*/
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:admin'])->group(function () {
  
    Route::get('/admin/home', [HomeController::class, 'adminHome'])->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/admin/link', [HomeController::class, 'adminHello'])->name('admin.hello');
    
});
  
/*------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
All Admin Routes List
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------*/
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:manager'])->group(function () {
  
    Route::get('/manager/home', [HomeController::class, 'managerHome'])->name('manager.home');
});
```

**LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
  
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
  
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
  
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
 
    public function login(Request $request)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();
     
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
     
        if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
        {
            if (auth()->user()->type == 'admin') {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }else if (auth()->user()->type == 'manager') {
                return redirect()->route('manager.home');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }
          
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
  
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    } 
  
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function adminHome()
    {
        return view('adminHome');
    }
  
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function managerHome()
    {
        return view('managerHome');
    }
}
```

**UserAccess**

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
  
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class UserAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $userType)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->type == $userType){
            return $next($request);
        }
          
        return response()->json(['You do not have permission to access for this page.']);
        /* return response()->view('errors.check-permission'); */
    }
}
```

Can you kindly help me?

Comment: You want to redirect 3 types of user to 3 different routes after login. 
But currently, every user is redirected to the route `/home`. This is your problem. Right?

Comment: @SAhmedNaim yes exactly, although the code is correct

Answer (score 0):

In most of my applications I have an admin panel.
Here's how I do the redirect logic:

I use the default `Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController` class from the breeze install.

My store method looks like this:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME);
    }

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

And of course in the RouteServiceProvider I hav my routes defined:

```
public const HOME = '/myorders';

public const ADMIN_HOME = '/admin/pages';
```

Comment: is there a tutorial showing this? To better understand what you are saying

Comment: But the problem that I am experiencing, did you manage to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

## **Solution 1:**

On your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`, just override the method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'Admin') {
        return "/admin/home";
        // or return route('admin.home');
    } 
    elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'Manager') {
        return "/manager/home";
        // or return route('manager.home');
    }

    return "/home";
    // or return route('home');
}
```

N.B: If something issue happenes with the method `redirectPath`, then please try with the method `redirectTo`. And must remove the property named `redirectTo` as well.

## **Solution 2:**

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (auth()->user()->hasRole(['Admin'])) {
        return redirect("/admin/home");
    } 
    elseif (auth()->user()->hasRole(['Manager'])) {
        return redirect("/manager/home");
    }

    return redirect("/home");
}
```

N.B: If you are using `Laravel Spatie Permission` package, then the permission checking would work in this way.

Comment: i get error **Undefined type 'Auth'**

Comment: Add the line `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` to the top of the file.
Besides, remove the forward slash from the `Auth`.

Comment: it already exists but it always gives me that error

Comment: Did you removed the forward slash before `Auth`?

Comment: yes but it always gives me the same error

Comment: On which file that error occurred? Would you please explain a little bit?
Or you may use the `auth()` helper method instead of `Auth` facade.
For example: `auth()->user()->hasRole(["Manager"])`.

Comment: Would you please mind sharing the error page which is triggered by the Laravel framework?

Comment: I'm no longer getting the error it gave me. Except that I always get **["You do not have permission to access for this page."]** when I try to log in as Admin or Manager. But does that function you wrote me have to be called up somewhere? or should it be replaced with a present code?

Comment: I think you don't give permission to the user types. Does it redirected successfully to the actual route?

Comment: and what should i do?

Comment: You must create a Role first. Then need to assign proper permission to the role. Then assign the role to the corresponding user. After that, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Does it redirected successfully to the actual route? If it does not take you to the actual route, then please try with my 2nd solution.

Comment: But where are these methods to be put? I understand that they go into the LoginController, but instead of which method?

Comment: You will just append the method to the LoginController. Actually, under the hood, your appended method will override the previous one which has been already declared within the trait `AuthenticatesUsers`, `RedirectsUsers`. Please have a look at these trait files first. And try to understand those. It will help you to write your own code very well.

Comment: Tried but still continue

Comment: Did u clear the `spatie permission` caches?
`php artisan cache:forget spatie:permission.cache` & `php artisan cache:clear`